# PHP ftp_nlist() - timeout

Tags: php, ftp

I have strange problem: I can connect to ftp server, create directory but I can not get a list of files in directory.

What could be wrong?

Facts:

- Server is behind firewall
- Yes, I use passive mode, as you can see from code
- PHP script is on the same server where FTP server is located
- I can access FTP from my desktop using FTP client, and everything works normal, I can create/upload and read contents of directories.
- `ftp_pwd()` and `ftp_mkdir()` work fast, `ftp_nlist()` and `ftp_rawlist()` wait for time-out specified in `ftp_connect()` (10 seconds in example case)
- In active mode - almost the same results (red-dir-functions fail immediately)

I think that problem not in the script but in ftp/server/firewall/access rights setup.

There is my code example:

```php
$conn = ftp_connect('my.host.here', 21, 10);

if (!$conn) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to connect to FTP');
}

$login_result = ftp_login($conn, 'login', 'password');
if (!$login_result) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to login to FTP');
}

// This is important part, because my server is behind frirewall/nat.
$paswRes = ftp_pasv($conn, true);
if (!$paswRes) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to enable passive FTP mode');
}

$resPwd = ftp_pwd($conn); //Returns: "/"

$resMkdir = ftp_mkdir($conn , 'testDir'); //Returns: "/testDir", creates new dir

$resNlist = ftp_nlist($conn, '.'); //Returns: bool(false)

$resRawlist = ftp_rawlist($conn, '.'); //Returns: bool(false)
```

**Upd:**

It works if host is `localhost`. So looks like problem is in firewall/ftp server setup.
I use `ProFtpd` on `Amazon EC2`

Passive ports specified as `PassivePorts                  49152 65534`

This range has been added as inbound port range in Amazon EC2 Security Groups `49152 - 65534    0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the problem.
It was FTP server misconfiguration (in my case - `ProFTPD` server):
Besides `PassivePorts` I had to specify `MasqueradeAddress`

```
MasqueradeAddress                <your-Ftp-Server-Domain-Name-Or-Ip-Address>
```

**Upd:** Also, check this article: http://www.elitehosts.com/blog/php-ftp-passive-ftp-server-behind-nat-nightmare/